# RedirectSignal error upon redirection via Java

Tags: xpages

I have designed the following method and using that within managed beans:

```
public static void redirectToPrevious() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    XSPContext xContext=XSPContext.getXSPContext(context);
    xContext.redirectToPrevious();
}
```

It works as expected. It redirects to the previous page (or home page if there is not any).

However, everytime it works, it throws RedirectSignal error:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: com.ibm.xsp.acl.RedirectSignal
at com.ibm.xsp.util.DataPublisher.publishControlData(DataPublisher.java:204)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.publishControlData(UIDataPanelBase.java:310)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.initBeforeContents(UIDataPanelBase.java:451)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.initBeforePageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:668)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:339)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildFacet(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:205)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UICallback.buildContents(UICallback.java:180)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.UIVarPublisherBase.buildContents(UIVarPublisherBase.java:97)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildPageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:692)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:340)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.buildContents(UIViewRootEx.java:1649)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2.buildContents(UIViewRootEx2.java:247)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createViewRoot(AbstractCompiledPage.java:167)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:521)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:251)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1315)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1299)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: com.ibm.xsp.acl.RedirectSignal
    at com.sun.faces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.xsp.actions.ExecuteScriptAction.invoke(ExecuteScriptAction.java:78)
    at com.ibm.xsp.actions.ActionGroup.invoke(ActionGroup.java:135)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.invoke(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:299)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.newDocument(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:126)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.load(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:97)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.getDataContainer(AbstractDataSource.java:474)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getDataObject(DominoDocumentData.java:145)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.pushData(AbstractDataSource.java:576)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.DataPublisher.publishControlData(DataPublisher.java:181)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.acl.RedirectSignal
    at com.ibm.xsp.designer.context.XSPContext.renderPage(XSPContext.java:194)
    at com.ibm.xsp.designer.context.XSPContext.redirectToPage(XSPContext.java:917)
    at com.ibm.xsp.designer.context.XSPContext.redirectToPage(XSPContext.java:929)
    at com.ibm.xsp.designer.context.XSPContext.redirectToPrevious(XSPContext.java:939)
    at com.developi.toolbox.BeanUtils.redirectToPrevious(BeanUtils.java:57)
    at com.hillside.flowng.beans.JobManager.postNewJob(JobManager.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.sun.faces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:138)
    ... 59 more
```

I can use try-catch and ignore the error but I'm not sure why this is happenning inside a managed bean but not in SSJS.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *RedirectSignal* is not a *java.lang.Exception*, it is a *java.lang.Error*. That's why it is not catched with a default try/catch block. There are some other signals f.e. the *NoAccessSignal* or the *ResponseCompleteSignal* which are handled internally to stop processing requests and/or code execution, but are not "real" errors for the XPages servlet.

When redirecting to another page, the *RedirectSignal* is required to stop processing "useless" code and is catched in SSJS Interpreter. A button with this code...

```
print("BEFORE!");
context.redirectToPrevious();
print("AFTER");
```

will just send the *BEFORE!* to the console, the rest of the SSJS will not be executed.

You have to handle the *RedirectSignal* by your own (in the method of your bean) to prevent the printing to the console / the log.

Comment: So this is actually used to stop further processing wherever used, right?

Comment: In SSJS yes. In your managed bean you have to watch for the signal and handle it by your own (it if required).

Comment: Thx Sven! I already trapped the error in try/catch in my Java code. One thing, as you said, it's not an exception, it should be trapped with either Throwable or RedirectSignal class in catch phrase.

Comment: I think it is the best to catch the RedirectSignal only. Catching all throwables and ignoring them is not the best idea... as long as the deadline is not tomorrow ;-)

Comment: The "com.ibm.xsp.acl.RedirectSignal" doesn't get thrown anymore in Domino 9.0.1 (FP2). Maybe IBM fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

`XSPContext.getXSPContext(FacesContext)` just uses the variable resolver to resolve the `context` variable, so this method *should* return a handle on the same object that `context` evaluates to within SSJS. So I'm not sure why you would see different behavior in different languages.

However, a `RedirectSignal` is only shown when recursion has been detected during a redirect. If I'm interpreting your stack trace correctly, `refreshMode` is set to `partial` on your event. All redirects must be performed from within a full refresh event.

Comment: That would make sense. I'm not using a partial refresh but I'm calling this method on "postNewDocument" event.

Comment: Nope, I tested on a button with full refresh. Still throws the error. SSJS somehow ignores the error I guess.